# upgrade project ios8 Xcode 6.0.1

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8

I have a project prior to the new xcode 6.0.1, and open it I get the following error as I can fix my project to upgrade the ios 8 ???

Apple LLVM 6.0 Error

clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/juliandavid/Google Drive/Trabajo/TuTurno/Codigo/IOS/TuTurno/TuTurno/TuTurno-Prefix.pch'
clang: error: no input files
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the folder in Library > Developer > Xcode > DerivedData > ModuleCache. Worked for us.

Comment: developer folder does not appear in the library folder